# When deleting a CoreData Object, how to also delete all of its related Objects in Swift5?

Tags: swift, core-data, entity, nsmanagedobject, nsset

I am currently working with `CoreData`.

**Problem:** I have a CoreData Entity **User** with a `one-to-many-relationship` to another CoreData Entity **Badges**. I am now trying to **delete a User** and, obviously, also would like to **delete all of his Badges**.

> Deleting the User itself is pretty straight forward:

```swift
context.delete(selectedUser)
```

> However I have to first delete all of the User's Badges. This is the complicated Part for me:

```swift
for badge in selectedUser.badges {
    context.delete(badge)
}
```

> When doing so, this Error occurs: **Cannot convert value of type 'NSSet.Element' (aka 'Any') to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'**

**My Possible Solution:** I was thinking of simple downcasting: `context.delete(badge as! NSManagedObject)`. However I am not sure whether this is possible.

**Question:** What is the best Practice for achieving the Goal I described above? Or is there maybe a CoreData way to recursively delete all related Objects?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just set the "Deletion Rule" for the relationship to "Cascade". Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528011/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for your answer. This does work perfectly and is much more clean than my approach. Just for Interest: Can you downcast NSSet.Element to NSManagedObject?

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: @MartinR Feel free to post this as your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedUser.badges` is an `NSSet` of `Badge`s, therefore you can cast its elements to `Badge` or to `NSManagedObject`:

```
for badge in selectedUser.badges {
    context.delete(badge as! NSManagedObject)
}
```

You can also cast the `NSSet` to its Swift counterpart `Set`:

```
for badge in selectedUser.badges as! Set<Badge> {
    context.delete(badge)
}
```

But in order to delete all related objects if a user is deleted, the simple solution is to set the “Deletion Rule” for the relationship to “Cascade”.